# Aache NIFI is it applicable to this use case?

Tags: apache-nifi

is this use case applicable to be implemented using NIFI
I want to develop a connector between two saas applications, to transfer data from system to system B. each application is multi-tenant. this connector works as the following

1. user insert in a form the authorization information for both systems
2. once authenticated the data will move on a scheduled basis to the other systems
3. not all the users in the saas will use this .. only group of them
4. data belonging for each user should not be overlapped with other users

Regards,

Comment: no specific requirements here and could be implemented with almost any technology.

Comment: I think using integration engines would make it easier, instead of developing if from scratch

Comment: i'm not saying you should not use one. you described task that could be implemented by any engine.